# RuntimeTools insight?

Tags: debugging

Does anyone happen to have some more complete insight into the `RuntimeTools` package that is used by `Debug` and Workbench?

I ask because, while I'm familiar with using `` RuntimeTools`Profile[] `` for global performance checking, there are times I'd rather focus the profiling more specifically. I'd also like to be able to monitor variable changes/ranges during an execution. (I know I can just set breakpoints, etc, but clicking 'continue' as a routine processes 1,000,000 or so vectors gets, well, tedious :) so I make due with tools like `Sow` and `Reap` but would prefer to not have to pollute my code so much.

`` ?RuntimeTools`* `` yields a nice assortment of intriguing routines, just wondering if anyone has taken the time to reverse-engineer their way through them.

(* Side Note - Anyone notice that, when turning on Debug w/in a package file editor notebook, MMa sometimes complains about syntax errors when you re-evaluate some cells, especially those with 'default values' for patterns on input? Under 10.x.x *)